# Substitute method in lambda expression

Tags: c#, lambda, delegates

I am writing unit tests for a series of similar methods defined on a single interface (this is a precursor to refactoring).  I'm finding that similar code shows up in multiple methods:

```
// Each line here shows up in a different test method.
mock.Setup(m => m.MethodA()).Returns(() => true);
mock.Setup(m => m.MethodB()).Returns(() => true);
mock.Setup(m => m.MethodC()).Returns(() => true);
```

I would like to create a single method into which I can pass the method to be tested, but am at a loss how to do this.  I'd like something that looks like this:

```
// testMethod is some method defined on IMyInterface.
private Mock<IMyInterface> SetupMockObject(Func<bool> testMethod)
{
    var mock = new Mock<MyInterface>();
    mock.Setup(m => m.testMethod()).Returns(() => true);
    return mock;
}
```

The call to this method would then look something like:

```
var configuredMockObject = SetupMockObject(MethodA);
```

Is this possible?

**EDIT**: An expression tree appears to be what I need - previously I didn't get the concept that you could pass lambda expressions around.  I've pasted the solution below since it took me a bit of fiddling to figure this out, although both dBurner's and Servy's answers proved helpful.

```
using Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting;
using Moq;
using Moq.Language.Flow;
using System;
using System.Linq.Expressions;

namespace ExampleTest
{
    [TestClass]
    public class TestClass
    {
        private Mock<IMyInterface> _mock;

        private interface IMyInterface
        {
            bool MethodA();
            bool MethodB();
        }

        private ISetup<IMyInterface, bool> SetupMockObject(Expression<Func<IMyInterface,bool>> lambda)
        {
            var mockSetup = _mock.Setup(lambda);
            return mockSetup;
        }

        [TestInitialize]
        public void Setup()
        {
            _mock = new Mock<IMyInterface>();
        }

        [TestMethod]
        public void TestMethodA()
        {
            SetupMockObject(i => i.MethodA()).Returns(true);     
            // Proceed with act and assert.
        }

        [TestMethod]
        public void TestMethodB()
        {
            SetupMockObject(i => i.MethodB()).Returns(true);
            // Proceed with act and assert.
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It's not clear what you mean - how would you call this?

Comment: What type is the parameter to `Setup`?  If it's an expression instead of a func it should be possible.

Comment: @JonSkeet I'm assuming `CommonTest(m => m.MethodA())` or something along those lines (possibly in a loop)

Comment: @DStanley: That *might* be the case - but it's not clear at the moment, to be honest.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The lambda that you pass to it needs to have a parameter of the mocked type, whereas your current parameter accepts a parameterless delegate:

```
public static Mock<MyInterface> SetupMockObject<T>(
    Func<MyInterface, bool> testMethod)
{
    var mock = new Mock<MyInterface>();
    mock.Setup(testMethod).Returns(() => true);
    return mock;
}
```

This allows you to write:

```
var mock = SetupMockObject(m => m.MethodA());
```

and have the code be equivalent to

```
var mock = new Mock<MyInterface>();
mock.Setup(m => m.MethodA()).Returns(() => true);
```

Comment: Shoudn't the `testMethod` parameter be an `Expression`?

Comment: @dburner It should be exactly the same type as what `Setup` accepts.  I don't know if it accepts delegates or expressions.

Answer (score 1):

You can use expression trees for this. Your `CommonTest` method should have a `Expression<Func<bool>>` parameter.

With this parameter type you can get the method name. after this you should construct another Expression that will represent `m => m.MethodFromParameter`.

Comment: Take a moment to read through the [editing help](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) in the help center. Formatting on Stack Overflow is different than other sites. You need to use backticks for inline code, or the editor will think it's html and remove it.

Comment: I wrote this from my phone, I was going to edit it :)

Comment: This is not a good approach, as it's way, way, more work than you need to do, and also an entirely incomplete answer, as you haven't even *discussed* large amounts of the work that would need to be done to use this approach.